# Sobre std::tuple, y como usarlo como miembro de una clase

Tags: c++, template, c++1z

Tengo una implementación que me funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
// clase de enteros modulo el parametro N
template<unsigned N> int_mod_N {
    unsigned m_i; // unico datro miembro
    /* ... implementacion ...*/
};

// clase que es una "tupla" de los anteriores enteros modulo N
// pero cada posicion de la tupla puede tener un modulo diferente
template<unsigned N_n,unsigned ... N_nm1>
struct producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns {
    int_mod_N<N_n> m_msd;
    producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns<N_nm1...> m_resto;
    // no hay mas datos miembros
    // implementacion utilizando recursion
};
```

El problema es que todo lo que hago ya está hecho en <**tuple**>. Sin embargo no sé como implementar los constructores, etc. Además esperaba que pudiese utilizar toda la tupla a la vez, sin tener que delegar en recursión. Pero no hay ningun tutorial en *youtube* o escrito que pueda comprender: no termino de comprender el uso de *std*::*integer_sequence*, ni el de *std*::*index_sequence*, que deberían de ser de ayuda. Lo que intento es un template de este tipo:

```
// clase que es una "tupla" de los enteros modulo N
// cada posicion de la tupla puede tener un modulo diferente
template<unsigned N_n,unsigned ... N_nm1>
struct producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns {
    std::tuple<int_mod_N<N_n>,int_mod_N<N_nm1>...> m_d;
    // no hay mas datos miembros
    // implementacion ????
};
```

Agradezco cualquier idea, o decirme algún sitio dónde ver algo que me ayude.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo del todo la pregunta, iría bien tener un caso práctico de uso. Con lo que he entendido creo que buscas esto:

```
template<unsigned ... N>
struct producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns {
    std::tuple<int_mod_N<N>...> m_tupla;

    template<typename ... V>
    producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns(V ... v) :
        m_tupla{std::tuple<int_mod_N<N>...>{int_mod_N<N>{static_cast<unsigned>(v)}...}} {}
};
```

Tu producto cartesiano tiene como miembro una tupla de enteros módulo, el constructor recibe una cantidad indeterminada de parámetros que serán convertidos a `unsigned` para construir la tupla interna. Puede ser usado así:

```
template <unsigned U>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const int_mod_N<U> &imN)
{
    return o << "MOD<" << U << ">(" << imN.m_i << ')';
}

template<unsigned ... N>
constexpr std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns<N...> &pcem)
{
    auto print = [&](auto &t){ o << t << ' '; };
    (print(std::get<int_mod_N<N>>(pcem.m_tupla)), ...);
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns<1,2,3,4,5> pcem(5,4,3,2,1);
    std::cout << pcem;
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> MOD<1>(5) MOD<2>(4) MOD<3>(3) MOD<4>(2) MOD<5>(1)
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/z9HJm3AIR1c5wYuA)</kbd>, pero has de tener en cuenta que:

- La cantidad de argumentos plantilla de `producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns` han de coincidir con la cantidad de argumentos de su constructor.
- Los parámetros pasados al constructor de `producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns` han de ser convertibles a `unsigned`.
- La sobrecarga del operador `<<` para `producto_cartesiano_enteros_modulos_Ns` sólo funciona si los argumentos plantilla son todos diferentes, en caso contrario se da una ambigüedad en el `std::get`.

Comment: Gracias voy a probar este código y pongo la solución completa, si la encuentro. De todas formas creo que me has dado lo que esperaba, el condtructor, que podría adminitir inicialización por lista, que me vendría muy bien. Gracias.

Comment: El constructor que te he propuesto no usa inicialización por lista, es variádico.

Comment: Ok. Aún así, aunque sea bajo paréntesis es un lista, no es importante que no una inlicialización por lista (entre llaves) propiamente dicha. De todas formas ¿Sería posible este tipo de inicialización?

Comment: Si, sería posible (pero notablemente más complicado) utilizar `const std::initializer_list<unsigned> &` como parámetro del constructor.

Comment: Perdona, si quiero reescribir esta pregunta (ya no es exactamente la misma) en otros términos, para poder avanzar, ¿abro una nueva que enlace con esta?

Comment: Si la pregunta es diferente, abre una nueva, si es la misma pregunta con otros matices, edita la pregunta presente.